# How to call a function (exported from a node module) by a button click event from a dom?

Tags: node.js, events, dom, button, click

please have a look on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbio8.jpg) which contains the snapshots of the

(a) directory structure, (b) main.js, (c) myModule.js, (d) index.html.

In case the link doesn't work, the directory structure is:

```
- root/
   - dist/
       bundle.js
   + node_modules/
   - src/
      main.js
      myModule.js
   index.html
   webpack.config.js
```

I have a function `myFunction` exported from `myModule.js` which somehow generates and plays a MIDI note. There also lives a `button` in the `index.html`. Now, when the user clicks the button (while the page being viewed in the browser), I want to call `myFunction()`. How can I do that?

I used `require` in `main.js` to include the exports of `myModule.js` and used webpack to make a `bundle.js` (please see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbio8.jpg)). But then I came to know that node.js doesn't have a native dom.

I found out that, it can be done using libraries/frameworks (e.g. React, etc). But is there anyway of doing it without using the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

In `main.js` replace the second line with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
     document
    .getElementById('myButton')
    .addEventListener('click', MyModule.myFunction());
});
```

And then bundle

Comment: Doesn't work. It throws an error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`
I think, this is happening because node.js doesn't know about the document or window or button or anything in the DOM. :-/

Comment: Did you bundle it and ran from the html with bundled js ?

Comment: Yes, I did. My only `<script>` tag in the `index.html` is loading the source from the `bundle.js`.

Comment: the script was possibly running before the dom had time to load. Try edited answer above.